# How to force xbee s2 end device to select a particular parent using api or at mode?

Tags: xbee, arduino-ide, topology, zigbee, mesh-network

Actually I want to implement XMesh protocol with XBee Series 2 modules.
I am implementing this protocol with 1 coordinator, 2 routers and 2 end devices.
According to this protocol, an end device should select its parent based on linkcost(linkcost = 1/(linkquality)).
This linkquality is measured by sending some messages(expected messages) to the 2 routers from 2 end devices. From the transmit status response I can count received messages using API mode arduino XBee library
(linkquality=(received messages)/(expected messages)).
These end devices each should select the one parent node among two routers.

But the problem here is XBee Series 2 modules are already having inbuilt protocol which is forming adhoc network on the fly. End devices are also choosing parent based on the whichever router provides best network coverage on the spot.

So how can i force end devices to select a particular router as its parent based on the minimum linkcost (i explained it above) using API mode (I am using Arduino XBee library) ?

Below is my network diagram..

[image]

BS-> Base station (Coordinator)

0,1-> routers

2,3-> end devices

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that will be possible -- the Series 2 modules will form a ZigBee mesh network following the ZigBee specification for choosing a parent.

If you are trying to form your own mesh network with different priorities (overall link cost to a base station, instead of best link quality of available routers), you might want to consider the [XBee Series 1](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-series1-module) modules, which don't have built-in mesh networking.

Is there a reason you feel that your method of choosing the parent is better than the methods currently used by the Series 2?

Comment: I'll add to this that XBee modules include an API frame type that allows you to specify source routing --  list of nodes to use as hops for the delivery of a message.  I believe this can be helpful on large networks where smart hosts can manage a routing table larger than what a typical ZigBee node can store.